# What could be an example of 'time' in a stochastic process where 'time' is not a natural time?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

I need any example of a stochastic process where 'time' is not a natural/real-world element what we generally call the time, and measure it using clocks/watches.

What could be an example of 'time' in a stochastic process where 'time' is not a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example is a [Poisson point process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process) in (say) the plane, that associates to each measuable set $A\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ a Poisson random variable $N(A)$ with expectation $\lambda(A)$ (where $\lambda$ is some measure), such that if $\lambda(A\cap B)=0$ then $N(A)$ and $N(B)$ are independent and $N(A\cup B)=N(A)+N(B)$.  Here the ''time'' space is something like $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^2)$, an object far larger (or at least more complicated) than $\mathbb R$.